# C++ Builder - Get the result of an Activity

Tags: android, c++, delphi, c++builder

I'm using C++Builder 10.1 Berlin to develop an Android app that scans barcodes. To do this, I'm calling another app (Zxing) when the user clicks on a button in my app, like this:

```
_di_JIntent intent;
if(Global->ClipService != NULL){
    Global->ClipService->SetClipboard(TValue::_op_Implicit(NULL));

    intent = TJIntent::Create();
    intent->setAction(StringToJString("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"));
    SharedActivity()->startActivityForResult(intent,0);
    scanCalled = true;    
}
else{
    ShowMessage("Presse Papier non disponible!");
}
```

To get the read barcode, I use the clipboard service. Until now, it was enough for me.

Now, I would like to get the type of the barcode. I need to handle Android's `onActivityResult` event. I found a solution in Delphi, but I'm not able to translate it to C++:

[Launching activities and handling results in Delphi XE6 Android apps](http://blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE6AndroidActivityResult/ActivityResult.htm)

In particular, the section titled ["Communication from the launched activity"](http://blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE6AndroidActivityResult/ActivityResult.htm#ActivityResults).

Indeed, the function `TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage()` needs a `TMessageListener` in C++, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the real problem is just that you don't understand how to call [`TMessageManager::SubscribeToMessage()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Messaging.TMessageManager.SubscribeToMessage) in C++. You should have started by reading the documentation, which includes C++ examples.

[Sending and Receiving Messages Using the RTL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Sending_and_Receiving_Messages_Using_the_RTL).

[Brian Long's Delphi example](http://blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE6AndroidActivityResult/ActivityResult.htm) would translate to the following in C++:

```
#include <System.Messaging.hpp>
//...

class TMainForm : public TForm
{
    //...
private:
    static const int ScanRequestCode = 0;
    int FMessageSubscriptionID;
    void __fastcall HandleActivityMessage(TObject* const Sender, TMessageBase* const M);
    bool __fastcall OnActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, _di_JIntent Data);
    //...
};
```

```
#include <FMX.Platform.Android.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.Helpers.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.App.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.Toast.hpp>
#include <LaunchActivities.hpp>

// ...

void __fastcall TMainForm::BarcodeScannerButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    FMessageSubscriptionID = TMessageManager::DefaultManager->SubscribeToMessage(__classid(TMessageResultNotification), &HandleActivityMessage);
    LaunchQRScanner(ScanRequestCode);
}

void __fastcall TMainForm::HandleActivityMessage(TObject* const Sender, TMessageBase* const M)
{
    TMessageResultNotification *msg = dynamic_cast<TMessageResultNotification*>(M);
    if (msg)
        OnActivityResult(msg->RequestCode, msg->ResultCode, msg->Value);
}

bool __fastcall TMainForm::OnActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, _di_JIntent Data)
{
    String ScanContent, ScanFormat;

    TMessageManager::DefaultManager->Unsubscribe(__classid(TMessageResultNotification), FMessageSubscriptionID);
    FMessageSubscriptionID = 0;

    // For more info see https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent
    if (RequestCode == ScanRequestCode)
    {
        if (ResultCode == TJActivity::JavaClass->RESULT_OK)
        {
            if (Data)
            {
                ScanContent = JStringToString(Data->getStringExtra(StringToJString("SCAN_RESULT")));
                ScanFormat = JStringToString(Data.getStringExtra(StringToJString("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT")));
                Toast(Format("Found %s format barcode:\n%s", ARRAYOFCONST(( ScanFormat, ScanContent ))), LongToast);
            }
        }
        else if (ResultCode == TJActivity::JavaClass->RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast("You cancelled the scan", ShortToast);
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```